# Register C++ function in Lua?

Tags: c++, lua

I am trying to register a c++ function in Lua.

But getting this error:

```
CScript.cpp|39|error: argument of type 'int (CScript::)(lua_State*)' does not match 'int (*)(lua_State*)'|
```

EDIT:

```
int CApp::SetDisplayMode(int Width, int Height, int Depth)
{
    this->Screen_Width = Width;
    this->Screen_Height = Height;
    this->Screen_Depth = Depth;

    return 0;
}

int CScript::Lua_SetDisplayMode(lua_State* L)
{
  // We need at least one parameter
  int n = lua_gettop(L);
  if(n < 0)
  {
    lua_pushstring(L, "Not enough parameter.");
    lua_error(L);
  }

  int width = lua_tointeger(L, 1);
  int height = lua_tointeger(L, 2);
  int depth = lua_tointeger(L, 3);

  lua_pushinteger(L, App->SetDisplayMode(width, height, depth));

  return 0;
}
```

And in main:

```
lua_register(L, "setDisplayMode", Lua_SetDisplayMode);
```

Comment: Can we see the snippet of source code that generates this error?

Comment: This is a simple function. Editing my post above in a moment.

Comment: The lua_register is line 39. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot *directly* register a C++ non-static member function in Lua using just the basic Lua C API.

However, any of the various mechanisms that exist for easily associating C++ code with Lua will allow you to do so. [toLua++](http://www.codenix.com/~tolua/), [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/), [Luabind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind.html), etc. If you're serious about using C++ objects with Lua, I suggest picking one of those and using it, rather than writing your own version. I personally use Luabind (most of the time; SWIG has its place in the toolbox), as it is the one that doesn't have some form of code generation. It's all done purely in C++, so there's no pre-pass step that generates a C++ source file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am also thinking about using luabind in my app.

Answer (score 8):

You can not use a method of a class as a normal function, unless it is declared `static`. You have to define a normal function, which finds out what object you want the method to be called in, and then call the method.

The main reason it's not possible to use a class method as a callback from a C function (and remember that the Lua API is a pure C library), is because the computer doesn't know which object the method should be called on.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is actually surprisingly simple; if you use lua_pushcclosure instead of lua_pushcfunction, you can pass parameters to your called function:

```
    lua_pushlightuserdata(_state, this);
    lua_pushcclosure(_state, &MyClass::lua_static_helper, 1);

    int MyClass::lua_static_helper(lua_State *state) {
        MyClass *klass = (MyClass *) lua_touserdata(state, lua_upvalueindex(1));
        return klass->lua_member_method(state);
    }
```

Comment: This is a nice way to go.  For people that want more information, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971131/registering-a-closure-with-lua and also the PIL https://www.lua.org/pil/27.3.3.html

Comment: Note that it didn't work for me until I added the call : lua_setglobal(_state, "functionName") as in the stackoverflow link above

Answer (score 0):

You can work around the limitation by storing your active `this` pointer in a static variable as well. This introduces the problem of being unable to have two of these classes operating at the same time, but it works.

```
static CScript* luaThis; // This is a private variable inside CScript.
```

Then, inside your `CScript` constructor (or some kind of 'activate' function), you can just specify:

```
luaThis = this;
```

Then, when your static functions are called (they can even be private functions if they are registered from within the class), you have access to all your member information via the `luaThis` pointer.

```
lua_pushinteger(L, luaThis->App->SetDisplayMode(width, height, depth));
```

The problem, as I said, is that this restricts you to one active CScript at a time (since another callback from another Lua state would use `luaThis` while it is pointing to the wrong things). If you need multiple active instances ever, you can come up with some lookup mechanism using the incoming `lua_State*` as a key.

```
std::map<lua_State*, CScript*> lookups; // Just an idea, if it comes to this.
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for showing how it is done. I am thinking to try Luabind first.